# Not Found (#404) Page not found.Yii2

Tags: php, url, yii2

Hello I have some issue with redirecting in Yii 2 , I have

```
 ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
                    ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
                    ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
                    ['label' => 'Tractor Models', 'url' => ['#']],
                    ['label' => 'Components', 'url' => ['#']],
                    ['label' => 'Users', 'url' => ['/loginuser/index']],
```

and I have file that is made in **LoginUser folder that have index** , generated by Gii ,and the redirecting dont work,I  I have problem with trying to "redirect" and other pages that I want . Can someone give me some clue about that problem ?

Comment: please add your `loginuser` controller code

Comment: make sure you have `public function actionIndex(){...}` in loginuser controller

Comment: public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new LoginUserSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
he is sthere ...

Comment: @vishu I add the controller code in 1 of the anwers

Comment: You should read this : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html#controller-class-naming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use `LoginUser` as your directory name then you can change to `login-user`.

Because `Url::to()` works separating words by hyphen.

Refer [yii\helpers\Url::to()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#to%28%29-detail)

```
['label' => 'Users', 'url' => ['/login-user/index']],
```

Comment: still Not Found #404 even if I change it ;/

Comment: if you use `LoginUser` as your directory name then you can change to `login-user` and then try

Comment: I make new file in site named proba , and then write just 1 echo 'with some text' , ['label' => 'Proba', 'url' => ['/site/proba']], I got again 404 ...

Comment: you create `action` in `SiteController` like `public function actionProba()
    { return $this->render('proba');}`

Comment: and then you create `proba.php` in **views->site** directory and write some text in `proba.php` file

Comment: yea it worked with that , I make actioncontroller for this , to try if the Url work but still dont work for the LoginUser.... and the actionIndex is there...

Comment: please give your `url`

Comment: you change `LoginUser` directory name to `login-user`

Comment: Now access a `index` file or not ?

Comment: It work with login-user / when I rename the Folder :) thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Whether you are using a [Nav](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-nav.html), [Menu](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-menu.html) or any other widget, the url parameter is always processed by [yii\helpers\Url::to()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#to()-detail).

When you declares this variable with `['/loginuser/index']`, you are saying that you have a file `app\controllers\LoginuserController.php` with a Controller class that have an `actionIndex()` method.

Be aware that all controllers (like any class in php) MUST be in [StudlyCaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studly_caps) (all words Capitalized). Your controller should be changed to LoginUserController (both file and class).

With that being said, now in your url parameter you will need to change (like @vishu suggested) to:

```
['/login-user/index']
```

Because `Url::to()` works separating words by hyphen.

I also would recommend you to take a look at the [PHP Standards Recommendations](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/) (especially num 1 to 4)